# malformed url using Jsoup in a talend job

Tags: csv, jsoup, talend, malformed

I'm using `telend` and I need to parse `HTML` using `Jsoup` library.
I put my links in a `CSV` file with `UTF-8` ecoding which I import with `tfileInputDelimited` then I use `Jsoup.connect` in the `javaflex` where I write my code in java to connect the site.
but when I use this code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect((String)globalMap.get("row1.site")).get();
```

I got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL
```

However, I'm able to connect to my link when I put it directly, without a `csv` file like this:

`Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/portal/desktop/en/opportunities/h2020/calls/h2020-cleanair-2015-1.html").get();`

Please, can anyone help me to resolve my problem or give any suggestion about the cause of the error?

Comment: have you tested tHTMLInput component from exchange? jsoup being used by this component and it has very good documentation as well. you can see more details on http://dwetl.com/2015/04/20/thtmlinput-parse-html-in-talend/ link.

Comment: yes I test it but I have some null xpaths  so I got error when it's null that's why I'm trying to code in a tjavaflex